# GoDaddy SMPT limit nodemailer issues

Tags: node.js, smtp, nodemailer

I am being told that the limit is 5 every 24 hours

I am trying to use Nodemailer to send emails from my GoDaddy email address. However, I am encountering a bizarre issue. This is the configuration of the createTransport function:

```
service: "Godaddy",
host: "smtpout.secureserver.net",
secureConnection: false,
port: 587,
auth: {
  user: "myemail@mydomain.com",
  pass: "mypassword",
},
```

It works. However, once I have sent 5 emails within a 24-hour period, it tells me I have hit the limit. This is the error message I receive:

```
Error: Mail command failed: 550 User [email_address] has exceeded its 24-hour sending limit. Messages to 5 recipients out of 5 allowed have been sent. Relay quota will reset in 16.50 hours.
  at SMTPConnection._formatError (C:\Users\[Username]\Desktop\nodemailer\nodemailer-form\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:790:19)
  at SMTPConnection._actionMAIL (C:\Users\[Username]\Desktop\nodemailer\nodemailer-form\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1594:34)
  at SMTPConnection.<anonymous> (C:\Users\[Username]\Desktop\nodemailer\nodemailer-form\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1063:18)
  at SMTPConnection._processResponse (C:\Users\[Username]\Desktop\nodemailer\nodemailer-form\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:969:20)
  at SMTPConnection._onData (C:\Users\[Username]\Desktop\nodemailer\nodemailer-form\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:755:14)
  at SMTPConnection._onSocketData (C:\Users\[Username]\Desktop\nodemailer\nodemailer-form\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:193:44)
  at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
  at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
  at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
  at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10) {
code: 'EENVELOPE',
response: '550 User [email_address] has exceeded its 24-hour sending limit. Messages to 5 recipients out of 5 allowed have been sent. Relay quota will reset in 16.50 hours.',
responseCode: 550,
command: 'MAIL FROM'
}
```

I have spoken to numerous customer support agents with GoDaddy who have assured me that my limit should be 500 emails per day. They have also mentioned that they can't help me since Nodemailer is a third-party application. I explained to them that Nodemailer itself sets no limits; however, they still say that everything is fine on their end. Is there any way I can change or fix this?

The weird thing is, I can still send emails from Outlook, just not from my web app through Nodemailer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here:
[Send email using Nodemailer with GoDaddy hosted email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44853483/send-email-using-nodemailer-with-godaddy-hosted-email)

The solution being the following:

```
host: "smtp.office365.com",  
    secureConnection: true,
    port: 587,
    auth: {
        user: "username@email.com",
        pass: "password"
    }
```

You also need to activate the smtp authentication on the email that you are using. This is done from your GoDaddy account.

Answer (score -1):

I've dealed with it....
try to use
host: 'smtp-mail.outlook.com'
port: 587

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).